# ActiveRecord Relation size strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have encountered some strange behavior of ActiveRecord Relation recently. 
Suppose, I have a `Stat` model with the following properies:

- `clicks`
- `views`
- `created_at`
- and others

Further suppose I have the following scope:

```
scope :aggregated, select('SUM(clicks) as clicks, SUM(views) as views).group('DATE(created_at)')
```

As a result I expect to get an array of Stat object with info aggregated by day, and so it is. But now consider this:

```
# in one place
a = Stat.aggregated    
#in other place
if a.size > 0
  'do stuff'
else
  'do other stuff'
end
```

And **it works fine** if `a` relation **is loaded**, but when `a` is not loaded it fails with `method undefined` error.
It turns out that when relation is not loaded size calls `count` on that relation, which essentially changes the query, returns a hash, and brakes the code.

**Is it an implied behavior?**

For me it is kind of counter-intuitive to change method semantics depending on whether relation was loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

That's how ActiveRecord Relation works. You can convert it into an array and do a size on it.

```
a = Stat.aggregated.to_a  
#in other place
if a.size > 0
  'do stuff'
else
  'do other stuff'
end
```